# Polymer Repeat in Template Is Not working

Tags: polymer, web-component

So I have a polymer element, which uses a nested template with repeat attribute. But it doesnt seem to recognize the JSON object being passed in.

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-localstorage/core-localstorage.html">

<polymer-element name="to-do">
    <template>
        <style>
           :host {
               display: block;
               background: white;
               height:400px;
               width: 300px;
               padding: 20px;
           } 
           paper-input {
               width: 70%;
               margin: 10px;
               display: inline-block;
           }
           core-icon {
               margin: 55px 10px 10px 10px;
               display: inline-block;
           }
           paper-checkbox {
               display: block;
               width: 100%;
           }
        </style>
        <paper-input floatingLabel label="Enter a Task"></paper-input> <core-icon icon="add-circle"></core-icon>
        <div class="tasks">
            <template repeat="{{item in tasklist}}">
                <paper-checkbox label="{{item.itemName}}"></paper-checkbox>
            </template>
        </div>
        <core-localstorage name="tasks" value="{{tasklist}}"></core-localstorage>
        
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('to-do', {
            tasklist: [
                {
                    itemName : "Study",
                    isDone : true
                },
                {
                    itemName : "Cook Dinner",
                    isDone : false
                }
            ],
            ready: function() {
                console.log(this.tasklist);
            },
            addObject: function() {
                    
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

It doesnt seem to get `tasklist` from the script block in the nested template block, but prints it out in the `ready` block.

You Can see a running demo of the above code here 
https://to-do-prateekjadhwani.c9.io/demo.html

Thanks

*****EDIT****

Since, it was using localstorage, it was using data in tasklist from LocalStorage rather than updating itself with the code iteration. 
So, I believe that this issue is resolved. But feel free to add comment(s) if you think that my reasoning isn't correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link does seem to be [working](http://i.imgur.com/s2n8Nhx.png) for me, or am I missing something?

Comment: @arbitter, I just checked, the link is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, it was using localstorage, it was using data in tasklist from LocalStorage rather than updating itself with the code iteration. So, I believe that this issue is resolved.